# Sharepoint's event flow giving me problems

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have been fooling around with SharePoint 2010 and to be honest I don't have any problem except maybe how the event flows are handled. I might be missing something.

As of right now I have a visual web part which has a button in its control and a label for simple text outputs. So I made myself a test model object (simple object class named `CounterModel` with a `int` property) so I could easily keep track of it with the view state.

So in my web part's init function I check if `ViewState[ID_COUNTER_MODEL]` is equal to null. If it is I create a new `CounterModeland` add it to the viewstate and if it isn't null i simply add my `ViewState[ID_COUNTER_MODEL]` to my private property of type `CounterModel`.

After the init I add an event listener of type mouse click on the button. The problem I am facing is that when I press the button the form is disposed, recreated and then calls my event listener wich results in reassigning my CounterModelobject from `ViewState[ID_COUNTER_MODEL]`. So any changes in the event listener are never really registered. What am I doing wrong and how should I handle these kind of situations.

Here are some code example:

**TestCounter Object**

```
class CounterModel
{
    public int number;

    public CounterModel() {
        number = 0;
    }
}
```

**Visual Web Part**

```
private CounterModel counterModel;

public CounterWebPart() {
    if (ViewState[CounterPropertiesIndexes.ID_COUNTER_MODEL] != null){
        counterModel = (CounterModel)ViewState[CounterPropertiesIndexes.ID_COUNTER_MODEL];
    } else {
        counterModel = new CounterModel();
        ViewState[CounterPropertiesIndexes.ID_COUNTER_MODEL] = counterModel;
    }
}

    protected override void CreateChildControls(){
        CounterWebPartUserControl control = (CounterWebPartUserControl)Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);

        control.GetBtnChangeLabel().Click += OnBtnChangeLabelClicked;
        control.GetLabel().Text = counterModel.number.ToString();
    }



    public void OnBtnChangeLabelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        counterModel.number++;
        (CounterModel)ViewState[CounterPropertiesIndexes.ID_COUNTER_MODEL] = counterModel;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue with SharePoint's event model, it's an issue with the event model of ASP.Net WebForms.  Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx for more information, but ViewState will never be populated in your control's constructor, so you're always building a new `counterModel` - that's why you're not seeing the number increment.  Try running that code in `OnLoad`.

Additionally, you shouldn't rely on when CreateChildControls is called relative to your event handlers (under certain conditions it gets called at different points in the process).  It should be used to create controls add them to the tree, and wire events.  Ie. don't call `control.GetLabel().Text = counterModel.number.ToString();` then, do it in `OnPreRender`.